# Density of Numbers with Exactly One Prime Factor of Multiplicity 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, distribution-of-primes

Let $S$ be the set of positive integers $n$ with the property that exactly one prime factor of $n$ has multiplicity $1$ and every other prime factor has multiplicity greater than $1$ (to be clear, $S$ does not contain the prime numbers). What is the asymptotic behavior of $\frac{\#\{n \in S' : n \leq X\}}{\#\{n \leq X\}}$ in the limit as $X \to \infty$?

What I know:
There is an easier analogue of this problem that I have an approach for, namely finding the density of the set $S'$ of positive integers $n$ such that every prime factor of $n$ has multiplicity greater than $1$. It is not hard to check that
$$\frac{\#\{n \in S' : n \leq X\}}{\#\{n \leq X\}} \leq \int_{1}^X (X/n^2)^{1/3} dn \approx 3 \sqrt{X}.$$
I suspect that the density of $S$ must be in the literature somewhere, but I can at least use the density of $S'$ to get an upper bound on the density of $S$ as follows:
$$\frac{\#\{n \in S : n \leq X\}}{\#\{n \leq X\}} \leq \sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{\#\{n \in S' : n \leq X/p\}}{\#\{n \leq X/p\}} \leq \sum_{p \text{ prime}}3 \sqrt{X/p} \ll X/\log X,$$
where in the last step above, I've used a well-known estimate for the sum of the reciprocals of the square roots of the prime numbers. Can one do better than $X/\log X$? (Is a power savings possible?)

Comment: aka square free multipliers on squareful numbers.

Comment: [OEIS A056169](https://oeis.org/A056169) suggests that up to $X=10000$ you have $2956$ such numbers if you include the primes and so $1727$ if you exclude the primes.  This is rather larger than $\frac{10000}{\log_e 10000} \approx 1085.7$.  Or are you suggesting $0.1727 \ll 1085.7$, which is certainly true though not enlightening?

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the OEIS reference!! The $\ll$ sign includes an implied constant that's approximately equal to $2$, so there isn't a contradiction.

Comment: Further savings is definitely not possible, since this set contains every integer of the form $4p$ where $p$ is an odd prime, and so the counting function is $\ge \pi(x/4)-1 \gg x/\log x$. By the way, your set $S'$ is the set of *powerful numbers*, and its counting function is known to be asymptotic to $\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}\sqrt x$.

Comment: Let $F(s) =1+ \sum_{n \in S'}n^{-s}= \prod_p (1+\frac{p^{-2s}}{1-p^{-s}}), \quad P(s) = \sum_p p^{-s}$ you want to  look at $$ \sum_{n \in S}n^{-s}= \sum_p p^{-s}( \frac{F(s)}{1+\frac{p^{-2s}}{1-p^{-s}}}-1) = -P(s) + F(s) P(s)+F(s)R(s)$$ 
where $R(s) = \sum_p p^{-s} (\frac{1}{1+\frac{p^{-2s}}{1-p^{-s}}}-1)$ is a Dirichlet series converging absolutely for $\Re(s) > 1/3$. With the standard tauberian theorems it gives $\sum_{n \le x,n\in S} 1 \sim (F(1)-1)\frac{x}{\log x}$

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan Your definition of $S$ implies it does contain the primes.